# ggplot scatter plot of two groups with superimposed means with X and Y error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I generate a ggplot2 scatterplot of two groups with the means indicated together with X and Y error bars, like this?

[image: Scatter plot]

Here is a reduced example (using `dput` to recreate the data.frame `df`) with two groups of cells and three measures, and I'd like to say plot `Peak` against `Rise`, or `Peak` against `Decay`. That much is straightforward, but I would like to add points indicating the group means with X and Y error bars (+/- sem).

Is there a way to do this within ggplot2, or do I need to generate means and sem values first? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231702/ggplot2-adding-two-errorbars-to-each-point-in-scatterplot) post draw my attention to `geom_errorbarh` but I'm still uncertain as to the best way to proceed.

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Peak = c(102.975, 
37.805, 64.996, 66.36, 199.354, 7.425, 34.137, 366.59, 10.165, 
14.833, 702.525, 39.086, 8.286, 122.783, 105.762, 37.018), Rise = c(0.346855, 
0.24165, 0.24028, 0.461548, 0.194016, 0.164047, 0.484375, 0.307861, 
0.438538, 0.488083, 0.549423, 0.365448, 0.511551, 0.33596, 0.331467, 
0.270096), Decay = c(1.3874, 1.07407, 1.88787, 2.64408, 1.1462, 
0.615963, 4.04641, 1.48701, 3.61397, 4.1838, 1.92746, 3.64329, 
4.21354, 0.812695, 1.14611, 1.28279)), .Names = c("Group", 
"Peak", "Rise", "Decay"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

ggplot(df, aes(Peak, Rise)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=Group)) +
  theme_bw(14)
```

I have tried something like:

```
library(doBy)

sem <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x))
z<-summaryBy(Peak+Rise+Decay~Group, data=df, FUN=c(mean,sem))
z
```

to get the values, but easily (and flexibly) incorporating them into the ggplot code is defeating me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use **plyr** for these kinds of summaries:

```
z <- ddply(df,.(Group),summarise,
            Peak = mean(Peak),
            Rise = mean(Rise),
            PeakSE = sqrt(var(Peak))/length(Peak),
            RiseSE = sqrt(var(Rise))/length(Rise))

ggplot(df,aes(x = Peak,y = Rise)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = Group)) + 
    geom_point(data = z,aes(colour = Group)) +
    geom_errorbarh(data = z,aes(xmin = Peak - PeakSE,xmax = Peak + PeakSE,y = Rise,colour = Group,height = 0.01)) + 
    geom_errorbar(data = z,aes(ymin = Rise - RiseSE,ymax = Rise + RiseSE,x = Peak,colour = Group))
```

[image]

I confess I was a little disappointed that I had to manually tweak the crossbar height. But thinking about it, I guess that could be fairly challenging to implement.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I am now wondering how to generalise this such that  I name the variables only once and make it easy to apply to different pairs of measures...

Comment: If I don't need error bars, is it possible to plot the means without calculating them ahead of time (with ddply or whatnot)?  I see that it's possible to use `stat_summary` to do so to plot ymeans, but I can't figure out how to use that feature to simultaneously calculate xmeans.  (I'm not sure if this is the right venue to ask this question - if it's not, I can create a new post.)

Comment: @TaliaYoung Probably with `stat_summary` and `fun.data`, where your function would collapse both the x and y variables. But there's really nothing wrong with summarising outside of ggplot.

Comment: Okay, thank you!  And yes, before `ggplot` it hadn't even occurred to me that such a thing might be possible without calculating it beforehand! I'm getting spoiled.  :)

Comment: It is probably better to re-assign Peak and Rise after you calculate the standard error. On my machine, reassigning early results in NA.