# How to plot a bivariate plot with confidence interval for the x an y-axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

Both my x and y-axis have variation in it, and thus have a corresponding confidence interval (xaxis.CI low and xaxis.CI.up). I want to plot x vs yaxis with the vertical and horizontal CIs, colored by dose in ggplot2. I also want to connect all the points by a line

```
xaxis <- c(5,10,9,30,2,4)
yaxis <- c(15,10,90,3,12,6)
xaxis.cI.low <-  xaxis + 3
xaxis.cI.up <-  xaxis - 3
  
yaxis.cI.low <- yaxis - 3
yaxis.cI.up <- yaxis + 3

dose <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600)

df <- data.frame(xaxis, yaxis, xaxis.cI.low, xaxis.cI.up, yaxis.cI.low, yaxis.cI.up, dose)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answers in [ggplot2 : Adding two errorbars to each point in scatterplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231702/ggplot2-adding-two-errorbars-to-each-point-in-scatterplot) is what you need:

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(x=xaxis, y=yaxis, color=dose)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=yaxis.cI.low, ymax=yaxis.cI.up)) + 
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=xaxis.cI.low, xmax=xaxis.cI.up))
```